# How to highlight markeddown code syntax in html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to integrate dynamic response as event/stream  (coming from a gpt api). Event source is printing properly but all as text. out of them have code snippet with triple backticks as

````
```javascript
var s = "JavaScript syntax highlighting";
window.alert(s);
var num = 42;
```
````

but it is not highlighting , I have used highlight.js lib but only syntax inside **pre** **code** is highlighted which I added manually. But I need dynamic highlighting. here is what I did.

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>AJAX Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/styles/default.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <p style="white-space: pre-wrap">
    ```javascript
    var s = "JavaScript syntax highlighting";   //not highlighiting
    window.alert(s);
    var num = 42;
    ```
  <pre><code class="language-javascript">
      var s = "JavaScript syntax highlighting";  //highlighiting
      window.alert(s);
      var num = 42;
      </code></pre>

  </p>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
  <script>hljs.highlightAll();</script>

</body>

</html>
````

where am I going wrong...any way or alternative. Please suggest.

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do.  The library doesn't latch onto EVERY tag you have.

Comment: you mean triple backticks  "wont interpret as code syntax...if no any alternatives

Comment: I don't understand your expectation...[highlightjs readme](https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html) _This will find and highlight code inside of <pre><code> tags; it tries to detect the language automatically._

Comment: No.  The module only looks for Markdown elements inside certain tags.  By default, it only looks in `<code>` tags, but the answer can show you how to do it for other tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a RegEx to find and replace those.

````js
const regexCode = /```(?<lang>\w*)\n+(?<code>.*?)```/gs

let rawText = document.querySelector("p").innerHTML

document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = rawText.replaceAll(regexCode, '<pre><code class="language-$1">$2</code></pre>')
````

````html
  <p style="white-space: pre-wrap">
    ```javascript
    var s = "JavaScript syntax highlighting";   //not highlighiting
    window.alert(s);
    var num = 42;
    ```
  </p>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.9.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
  <script>hljs.highlightAll();</script>
````

Comment: thanks for understanding my requirement....your stuff is working well but this is manual process....I have markdown format is there any way to interpret it....as I will have multiple marked syntax like double * Using StringBuilder: double*...which will print as bold

Comment: @Joe in that case, I think it's better to use a package like [showdownjs](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) to do the conversion